Question regarding the proof of Dedekind's Factorisation Theorem in Stewart and Tall
In Stewart & Tall's "Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem" (4ed, p.170; see picture below) the authors make the statement that for a polynomial $\overline{f}_i$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$  with root $\theta_i$ holds
$$\mathbb{Z}_p[\theta_i] \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p[t] / \langle \overline{f}_i \rangle.$$
I do not understand why this is the case, could you please explain this to me?


This is a basic result from field theory.  If $K$ is a field, and $h(X) \in K[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial, then the quotient ring
$$L = K[X]/\langle h(X) \rangle$$
is a field which essentially contains $K$ as a subfield.  The polynomial $h(X)$ now has a root in $L$, namely the image of the indeterminate variable $X$ in $L$.
If $\overline{K}$ is an algebraic closure of $K$, and $b$ is a root of $h(X)$ in $\overline{K}$, then the simple field extension $K(b)$ is isomorphic to $L$.  This is obvious, because an expression of the form
$$a_0 + a_1 b + a_2 b^2 + \cdots +a_mb^m \tag{$a_i \in K$}$$
can be associated to the image of the polynomial
$$a_0 + a_1X + a_2X^2 + \cdots + a_mX^m$$
in $L$.
Thus, $K[X]/\langle h(X) \rangle$ can always be thought of as the field obtained by adjoining a single root of $h(X)$ to $K$.
